# Using ajax to load drop down lists

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, button, postback, html.dropdownlistfor

I am very new to ajax. Can someone explain to me how this works and what I need to do for my scenario below.

I have a drop down list and a button.

I choose and item from the drop down list ("ex: Car Type")

and press the get types button.

Another drop down list with different types will be populated.

Those are the steps I use. How can I use Ajax instead of post back and refreshing the page please.

Thanks

Comment: Could you paste the code you refer to?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17107860/populate-drop-down-list-with-jquery-on-button-click-in-mvc