# populate drop down list with Jquery on button click in mvc

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, model, html.dropdownlistfor

I am very new to jQuery, is there by any chance some code using jQuery that I can use to populate a drop-down list with in MVC?

I am using MVC models to populate drop-down lists at the moment. How can I populate a drop-down list with jQuery to avoid posting back to the server?

At the moment I am using json as follows:

Controller:

```
   [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public JsonResult GetTeams(StatisticModel model)
    {
        StatisticModel newModel = new StatisticModel(model.leagueId);
        var teams = newModel.getTeams;
        return Json(teams);
}
```

View:

```
<%: Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.leagueId, Model.getLeagues, new { @class = "dropdownlistLeagueStyle" })%></td><td><input id="leagueButton" class="loginButton" value="GetTeams" type="submit" />

<select id="LeagueTeams"></select>
```

Javascript

```
$(function() {
$(".dropdownlistLeagueStyle").change(function () {
    $.getJSON("/Admin/GetTeams", { LeagueId: $(".dropdownlistLeagueStyle").val() },
  function (teams) {
      $("#LeagueTeams").empty();
      $.each(teams, function (i, team) {
         $("#LeagueTeams").append($("<option>" + team.Text + "</option>"));
     });
  });
  });
  })
```

However, I am getting an "expecting more source characters" error in the last bracket, and getting this data when testing:

```
[{"Selected":false,"Text":"Arsenal","Value":"1"},
{"Selected":false,"Text":"Aston Villa","Value":"3"},
{"Selected":false,"Text":"Cardiff City","Value":"20"},
{"Selected":false,"Text":"Chelsea","Value":"4"},
{"Selected":false,"Text":"Crystal Palace","Value":"22"}, 
{"Selected":false,"Text":"Everton","Value":"5"},
{"Selected":false,"Text":"Fulham","Value":"6"},
{"Selected":false,"Text":"Hull City","Value":"21"},
{"Selected":false,"Text":"Liverpool","Value":"7"},
{"Selected":false,"Text":"Manchester City","Value":"8"},
{"Selected":false,"Text":"Manchester United","Value":"9"},
{"Selected":false,"Text":"Newcastle United","Value":"10"},
{"Selected":false,"Text":"Norwich","Value":"11"},
{"Selected":false,"Text":"Southampton","Value":"13"},
{"Selected":false,"Text":"Stoke City","Value":"14"},
{"Selected":false,"Text":"Sunderland","Value":"15"},
{"Selected":false,"Text":"Swansea City","Value":"16"},
{"Selected":false,"Text":"Tottenham Hotspur","Value":"17"},
{"Selected":false,"Text":"West Bromwich Albion","Value":"18"},
{"Selected":false,"Text":"West Ham United","Value":"19"}]
```

Not in the drop down list

Comment: Can you give an example of what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: Basically I have a drop down list with a list of soccer league. when a soccer league is chosen and a button to get teams is clicked. 2 drop down lists will be populated with the teams from that leagues. ok ? –

Answer (score 1):

You have to append `<option>` to a select. Not just a string. Also, you are using `team.name`. In your result set, there is no "name" property on each object. There is however `team.Text`.

`$("#LeagueTeams").append($("<option>" + team.Text + "</option>"));`

```
$(function() {
    $(".dropdownlistLeagueStyle").change(function() {
        $.getJSON("/Admin/GetTeams", {
            LeagueId: $(".dropdownlistLeagueStyle").val()
        }, function(results) {
            $("#LeagueTeams").empty();
            $.each(results, function(i, team) {
                // append an option with the team name in there
                $("#LeagueTeams").append($("<option>" + team.Text + "</option>"));
            });
        });
    });
});
```

I have made a jsFiddle using the results you are getting and a select.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/joshthecoder/jKdwm/)

On another note, you might want to change your return type on the controller action to `JsonResult` instead of `ActionResult`.

Comment: try this `$("#LeagueTeams").append($("<option>" + team.name + "</option>"));`

Comment: same stuff all the data keep showing in another page :S and got a green error at the end of javascript "Expecting more source characters"

Comment: still having problems dont know why...updated my code in this post. Check it out please. Thanks

Comment: Try removing `[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]` from the action. By default the `$.getJSON` call does a GET, not a POST.

Comment: Sorry also, you will need to replace it with `[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]`. `JsonResult` will expect a POST if not specified as allowing a GET.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31790/discussion-between-mark-fenech-and-joshthecoder)